# gerivedStateFromProps doesn't trigger but componentWillReceiveProps did

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've used gerivedStateFromProps in https://codesandbox.io/s/pm0yvwp2jj (containers/dashboard/index.js) but I couldn't see any trigger in gerivedStateFromProps. I checked my package.json both react and react-dom is 16.3, what's wrong?

Comment: @nrgwsth You've got it wrong also. It's `getDerivedStateFromProps` https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo there:

```
static gerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    console.log(nextProps); //not working?
  }
```

should be

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    console.log(nextProps); //not working?
  }
```

For clarity, not **gerivedStateFromProps**, it is **getDerivedStateFromProps**.

Also just instead of giving just the sandbox itself if you put the relevant code her it would be nice. So people can easily see the mistakes like this.